# Spark nodes communicating using wrong IP address (Docker)

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-compose, datastax-enterprise

I have a Spark (DataStax enterprise) cluster created using Docker, tied together using `docker-compose`. This is for local development purposes only.

The containers are in their own docker network: `172.18.0.0/16`. I'm on a Mac running Docker toolbox, and I am able to access the containers directly from my machine as I've manually added a route to `172.18.0.0/16` over `vboxnet0`, the virtual network Virtualbox provides on the Mac.

My side of the `vboxnet0` interface has the IP `192.168.99.1`. The docker-machine side has `192.168.99.101`.

This all works great, the master web UI comes up on `172.18.0.2:7080`, and all of the nodes are shown correctly, with their `172.x` IP addresses (and continue to do so if I scale out via e.g. `docker-compose scale spark=5`).

However, when I submit jobs, e.g.:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://172.18.0.2:7077 --class myapp.Main \
./target/scala-2.10/myapp-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`,

It is very slow (I presume due to retrying), and I see errors like this, until it finally succeeds:

```
16/09/16 13:01:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, 192.168.99.101): org.apache.spark.storage.BlockFetchException: Failed to fetch block from 1 locations. Most recent failure cause:
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemote(BlockManager.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraJoinRDD.compute(CassandraJoinRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.99.101:35306
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.access$200(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher$1.run(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.99.101:35306
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    ... 1 more
```

However, I don't know why it is attempting to access resources on `192.168.99.101`, the gateway.

I also see output like this, which again does not show the IP address I expect:

```
16/09/16 13:01:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4, 192.168.99.101, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2316 bytes)
16/09/16 13:01:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, 192.168.99.101, partition 0,NODE_LOCAL, 2089 bytes)
16/09/16 13:01:36 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on 192.168.99.101:39885 (size: 7.5 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
16/09/16 13:01:51 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on 192.168.99.101:35306 (size: 7.5 KB, free: 511.0 MB)
```

I've tried setting `SPARK_LOCAL_IP=192.168.99.1` on the Mac, and to each node's `172.x` address within `spark-env.sh` on the nodes, but it did not help.

I'm able to access all nodes directly from the Mac, and they can also route to both the `docker-machine` VM (`192.168.99.101`), and out to the Mac (`192.168.99.1`). Each node can also route to the others both by name, and by IP address.

Am I correct that the BlockManager seems to be using the wrong IP address? Is there some way to force it to use the correct one, rather than the gateway address it is somehow picking up?

Edit: Just to add - I've also attempted to set the blockmanager port to a hardcoded one, as clearly the randomly assigned one won't match anything I can `EXPOSE` whether or not the IP address is correct, but that doesn't appear to be working. I did this by setting `-Dspark.blockManager.port=7005` in both `SPARK_MASTER_OPTS` and `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS`.

Edit 2: If I put Java, Spark, and my App Jar onto a new, empty container (on the same 172.18/16 network), and launch the job via `spark-submit` from there (ie no traffic over the gateway, only container-to-container, everything works as expected. It seems to be some issue where the gateway IP for the host is used when submitting from the other side of the gateway.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have similar problem now.

Comment: @MarcinLagowski I'm afraid not, still stuck! I've also considered using Docker OSX (instead of via Docker toolbox), but you have to do some hackery (see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22753) to even access the containers directly by IP from the host in that case - so it's not much of an alternative!